# Improve The Accuracy of Validation accuracy of LSTM Model

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, lstm

I trying building LSTM model to predict next words but I get low accuracy

when I do train my LSTM model on Arabic Dataset callled ASTD after I split it into 70% train and 30% test , I always get low accuracy in testing.
How Could I improve the accuracy at least 50% of testing

my architecture to build the model
total words= 27233
I used FastText word embedding with 300 dim

result I get after fit the model :
Maximum Training Accuracy (7.61%): 6.7052
Maximum Validation Accuracy (6.74%): 12.8832

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=total_words,
                    output_dim=embedding_dim,
                    weights=[embedding_matrix],
                    input_length=max_sequence_len-1,
                    trainable=False))  # Making embedding layer trainable
model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True))  # Add LSTM layer
model.add(Dropout(0.3))  # Apply dropout separately
model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))  # Add LSTM layer
model.add(Dropout(0.2))  # Apply dropout separately
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))  # Apply a higher dropout rate here for regularization
model.add(Dense(total_words, activation='softmax'))
```